# Box Plot of grouped data in Pandas

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to plot a boxplot of a grouped dataset.

Imagine my data set looks like this

```
Gender | Age
------ | ------
Male   | 20
------ | ------
Female | 40
------ | ------
Female | 45
------ | ------
Unknown| 5
------ | ------
Male   | 80
------ | ------
Female | 30
------ | ------
Unknown| 50
------ | ------
Male   | 12
```

Now what I want to do is to plot a box plot which shows the Mean age of all three genders in the same plot figure which looks something like this:

[image: Multi Box plots]

Currently what I have done is to group my dataset by Genders.

```
data = data.groupby("Gender")
data["Age"].plot(kind="box")
```

But what this does is produce one box plot like this -

[image]

How do I unstack them and produce a more meaningful visualization?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out on my own.

Using the seaborn package, one can simply do this

```
sns.boxplot(data["Age"], groupby=data["Gender"])
```

and it renders a beautiful boxplot grouped

Comment: The groupby parameter causes the error as follows: `TypeError: Axes.bxp() got an unexpected keyword argument 'groupby'`.